# unable to add product to cart using woocommerce cart rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I created rest API for add product to cart, get customer cart, update cart products of woocommerce in WordPress but I'm getting an issue. Product added to the cart using API but when I run catomer cart API user cart from usermeta table gets deleted.
let me show below code for add to cart and get customer cart

```
//code for add to cart
public function agl_add_to_cart( $request ) 
{
    global $woocommerce,$wpdb;
    $cart_data = array();

    // Takes raw data from the request
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // Converts it into a PHP object
    $jdata = json_decode($json);

    $product_id     = ! isset( $jdata->product_id ) ? 0 : absint( $jdata->product_id );
    $quantity       = ! isset( $jdata->quantity ) ? 0 : absint( $jdata->quantity );
    $variation_id   = ! isset( $jdata->variation_id ) ? 0 : absint( $jdata->variation_id );

    $variation      = ! isset( $jdata->variation ) ? array() : $jdata->variation;
    $cart_item_data = ! isset( $jdata->cart_item_data ) ? array() : $jdata->cart_item_data;
    $user_id        = ! isset( $jdata->user_id) ? 0 : $jdata->user_id;
    $additional_info = !isset($jdata->additional) ? array() : json_decode($jdata->additional);
    $child = !isset($jdata->child) ? '' : $jdata->child;
    $adult = !isset($jdata->adult) ? '' : $jdata->adult;
    $infant = !isset($jdata->infant) ? '' : $jdata->infant;
    $adult_spectator = !isset($jdata->adult_spectator) ? '' : $jdata->adult_spectator;
    $child_spectator = !isset($jdata->child_spectator) ? '' : $jdata->child_spectator;
    $date = !isset($jdata->date) ? '' : $jdata->date;


    if(empty($user_id)){
        return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(0,'Please enter user id.'); die();
    }elseif(empty($product_id)){
        return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(0,'Please enter product id.'); die();
    }elseif(empty($quantity)){
        return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(0,'Please enter product quantity.'); die();
    }
    else
    {
        
        $variation = array();
        foreach ($jdata as $key => $value) {
            if(substr($key, 0 , 8) == "variant_"){
                $var = str_replace("variant_", "", $key);
                $variation[$var] = $value;
            }
        }
        if(!empty($variation_id) && empty($variation)){
            return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(0,'Please enter product variation.'); die();
        }
        if(empty($variation)){
            $variation = json_encode($variation);
        }   


        //Additional fields
        $fieldData = array('adult'=>'wt_number_adult','child'=>'wt_number_child','infant'=>'wt_number_infant','adult_spectator'=>'wt_number_ct1','child_spectator'=>'wt_number_ct2','date'=>'wt_date');
        $additional_data = array();
        $total_variation_prices = 0;
        if(!empty($variation_id)){
            $variation_additional_prices = $this->getVariationProduct_additionalprices($variation_id);
            
            $add_prices = [];

            $add_prices[$fieldData['adult']] = ($variation_additional_prices['adult']['sale'] > 0) ? $variation_additional_prices['adult']['sale'] : $variation_additional_prices['adult']['regular'];

            $add_prices[$fieldData['child']] = ($variation_additional_prices['child_spectator']['sale'] > 0) ? $variation_additional_prices['child_spectator']['sale'] : $variation_additional_prices['child_spectator']['regular'];

            $add_prices[$fieldData['infant']] = ($variation_additional_prices['infant']['sale'] > 0) ? $variation_additional_prices['infant']['sale'] : $variation_additional_prices['infant']['regular'];

            $add_prices[$fieldData['adult_spectator']] = ($variation_additional_prices['adult_spectator']['sale'] > 0) ? $variation_additional_prices['adult_spectator']['sale'] : $variation_additional_prices['adult_spectator']['regular'];

            $add_prices[$fieldData['child_spectator']] = ($variation_additional_prices['senior_spectator']['sale'] > 0) ? $variation_additional_prices['senior_spectator']['sale'] : $variation_additional_prices['senior_spectator']['regular'];
            
            $adprices = [];
            if(isset($date) && !empty($date)){
                $additional_data['date'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
            }

            if(isset($child) && !empty($child)){
                $adprices[] = (int)$add_prices[$fieldData['child']]*(int)$child;
                $additional_data['child'] = array('quantity'=>(int)$child,'price'=>(int)$add_prices[$fieldData['child']]);
            }
            if(isset($adult) && !empty($adult)){
                $adprices[] = (int)$add_prices[$fieldData['adult']]*(int)$adult;
                $additional_data['adult'] = array('quantity'=>(int)$adult,'price'=>(int)$add_prices[$fieldData['adult']]);
            }
            if(isset($infant) && !empty($infant)){
                $adprices[] = (int)$add_prices[$fieldData['infant']]*(int)$infant;
                $additional_data['infant'] = array('quantity'=>(int)$infant,'price'=>(int)$add_prices[$fieldData['infant']]);
            }
            if(isset($adult_spectator) && !empty($adult_spectator)){
                $adprices[] = (int)$add_prices[$fieldData['adult_spectator']]*(int)$adult_spectator;
                $additional_data['adult_spectator'] = array('quantity'=>(int)$adult_spectator,'price'=>(int)$add_prices[$fieldData['adult_spectator']]);
            }
            if(isset($child_spectator) && !empty($child_spectator)){
                $adprices[] = (int)$add_prices[$fieldData['child_spectator']]*(int)$child_spectator;
                $additional_data['child_spectator'] = array('quantity'=>(int)$child_spectator,'price'=>(int)$add_prices[$fieldData['child_spectator']]);
            }
            $total_variation_prices = array_sum($adprices);

        }

        $array = $wpdb->get_results("select meta_value from ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta where meta_key='_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1' and user_id = ".$user_id);

        $data =$array[0]->meta_value;
        $cart_data=unserialize($data);

        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if(empty($product)){
            return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(0,'ProductId not exists.'); die();      
        }
        $string = $woocommerce->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id, 0, array(), $cart_data['cart'] );
        $flag = 0;
        $cartid = "";
        foreach($cart_data['cart'] as $key => $val) {
            if($val['product_id'] == $product_id){
                $flag = 2;
                $cartid = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if($flag == 2){
            $cart_data['cart'][$string]['quantity'] = $cart_data['cart'][$string]['quantity']+$quantity;
            $price = $product->get_price();
            if(!empty($variation_id)){
                $price = $total_variation_prices;
            }
            $linesubtotal = $cart_data['cart'][$string]['quantity'] * $price;
            $cart_data['cart'][$string] = array(
                'key' => $string,
                'product_id' => $jdata->product_id,
                'variation_id' => $variation_id,
                'variation' => $variation,
                'additional' => $additional_data,
                'quantity' => ($quantity + $cart_data['cart'][$key]['quantity']),
                'line_tax_data' => array(
                    'subtotal' => array(),
                    'total' => array()
                ),
                'line_subtotal' => wc_format_decimal($linesubtotal,2),
                'line_subtotal_tax' => 0,
                'line_total' => $product->get_price(),
                'line_tax' => 0,
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $price = $product->get_price();
            if(!empty($variation_id)){
                $price = $total_variation_prices;
            }
            $linesubtotal = $quantity * $price;
            $cart_data['cart'][$string] = array(
                'key' => $string,
                'product_id' => $jdata->product_id,
                'variation_id' => $variation_id,
                'variation' => $variation,
                'additional' => $additional_data,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
                'line_tax_data' => array(
                    'subtotal' => array(),
                    'total' => array()
                ),
                'line_subtotal' => wc_format_decimal($linesubtotal,2),
                'line_subtotal_tax' => 0,
                'line_total' => $product->get_price(),
                'line_tax' => 0,
            );
        }

        update_user_meta($user_id,'_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1',$cart_data);
        return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(1,'Product added to cart successfully.',$cart_data); die();
    }
} // END add_to_cart()

/****Code for Get Customer cart****/

public function get_cart_customer( $data = array(), $cart_item_key = '' ) {
        if ( empty( $data['user_id'] ) ) {
            return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(0,'Please enter user id.'); die();
        }

        $saved_cart = $this->get_saved_cart( $data );

        // If a saved cart exists then replace the carts content.
        $cart_contents = array();
        if ( ! empty( $saved_cart ) ) {

            foreach ( $saved_cart as $item_key => $cart_item ) {

                if ( ! isset( $cart_item['data'] ) ) {
                    $cart_item['data'] = wc_get_product( $cart_item['variation_id'] ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'] );
                }
                $show_thumb = ! empty( $data['thumb'] ) ? $data['thumb'] : false;
                $_product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['data']->get_id() );

                $product_name  = $_product->get_name();
                $product_title = $_product->get_title();
                $product_price = $_product->get_price();
                $thumbnail_id = $_product->get_image_id();
                $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id);
                // Add main product image as a new variable.
                $product_image = esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] );
                $productid = ($cart_item['product_id'] != '') ? $cart_item['product_id'] : 0;
                $variation_id = ($cart_item['variation_id'] != '') ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : 0;
                $variation = array();

                if(!empty($cart_item['variation'])){

                    foreach ($cart_item['variation'] as $vkey => $vvalue) {
                        $variation[$vkey] = $vvalue;
                    }
                }

                $quantity = (!empty($cart_item['quantity'])) ? $cart_item['quantity'] : 0;

                $line_subtotal = (!empty($cart_item['line_subtotal'])) ? $cart_item['line_subtotal'] : 0;
                $line_subtotal_tax = (!empty($cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'])) ? $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'] : 0;
                $line_total = (!empty($cart_item['line_total'])) ? $cart_item['line_total'] : 0;
                $line_tax = (!empty($cart_item['line_tax'])) ? $cart_item['line_tax'] : 0;
                $additional = (!empty($cart_item['additional'])) ? $cart_item['additional'] : array();
                $variation = !empty($variation) ? $variation : json_decode('{}');
                $cart_contents[] = [
                    'user_id'=>(int)$data['user_id'],
                    'cart_id'=>$item_key,
                    'name'=>$product_name,
                    'title'=>$product_title,
                    'price'=>(int) $product_price,
                    'image'=>$product_image,
                    'product_id'=>(int) $productid,
                    'variation_id'=>(int) $variation_id,
                    'variation'=>$variation,
                    'additional'=>$additional,
                    'quantity'=>(int) $quantity,
                    'subtotal'=>(int) $line_total,
                    'subtotal_tax'=>(int) $line_subtotal_tax,
                    'total'=>(int) ($line_subtotal > 0) ? (int) $line_subtotal : (int)$line_total,
                    'tax'=>(int) $line_tax
                ];

                if($cart_contents[$c]['variation_id'] == 0){
                    unset($cart_contents[$c]['variation']);
                }

                $c++;
            }
        }
        return $this->algarvefun_def_return_arr(1,'Cart Items are fetched successfully.',$cart_contents); die();
        //return $this->get_cart_contents( $data, $cart_item_key );
    } // END get_cart_customer()
    
public function get_saved_cart( $data = array() ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $saved_cart = array();

        $customer_id = ! empty( $data['user_id'] ) ? $data['user_id'] : 0;

        $saved_cart_meta = get_user_meta( $customer_id, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1', true );
        $saved_cart = (array) $saved_cart_meta['cart'];
        
        if ( isset( $saved_cart_meta['cart'] ) ) {
            $saved_cart = array_filter( (array) $saved_cart_meta['cart'] );
        }
        return $saved_cart;
    } // END get_saved_cart()
```

Comment: That's a pretty big chunk of code to dissect. You need to narrow down where the issue is occuring. At what point does it get deleted?

Comment: Hi @InvictusMKS issue occurs at "function get_cart_customer" when i calling this function "_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1" key in usermeta table becomes blank
So that i unable get customer cart in api response.

Hope you get my point.